# Registration Handler - determining which Auth Provider was used to sign in

Tags: apex, single-sign-on, auth-provider, user-registration, third-party

We have many Auth Providers (all based on OpenID Connect) we are using to SSO into a Salesforce community. In order to add some logic to the Registration Handler that checks if a user already exists under a specific auth provider, I need the auth provider Id or Name to match against the fields `SsoProviderId` or `SsoProviderName`.

I'm not seeing a way to determine which auth provider was used to sign in and then subsequently triggered the invocation of the registration handler. Code I am trying to fix:

```
    Boolean error = false;
    List<User> users = [
        SELECT Id
        FROM User
        WHERE Contact.AccountId = :accountId
    ];

    if (users.size() < 1) {
        return error;
    }
    List<ThirdPartyAccountLink> tpals = [
        SELECT
            Id,
            SsoProviderId,
            SsoPRoviderName,
            Handle,
            ThirdPartyAccountLinkKey,
            UserID
        FROM ThirdPartyAccountLink
        WHERE userId IN :users
    ];
    if (tpals.size() < 1) {
        return error;
    }

    System.debug('SECURITY CHECK # USERS: ' + tpals.size());
    for (ThirdPartyAccountLink tpal : tpals) {
        if (tpal.SsoProviderId == provider) {
            error = true;
        }
    }

    return error;
```

Comment: SF performs the "does user exist" check before calling `create` or `update` method on your reg handler. Haven't investigated this but it should take the provider (name/id/etc) into consideration when performing this check, no?

Comment: That is correct - the check happens just prior to SF deciding which of the two methods to invoke. I believe the key is the ThirdPartyAccountLinkKey althought the documentation falsely indicates the RemoteIdentifier must be unique (which is only true for each provider). I do not have access to any of the parameters SF uses on that check and was surprised no System or Auth namespace class/method covers this specific use case.

Comment: I don't have a solution but just another question as I'm having a related issue. Which user do you add to the debug log? I added the Site Guest user/ System user but none of them showed up in the log when I'm was trying to log in. So I cannot tell if the code was even called.